# Do we have to always use self.variable while using them in some expression?

Tags: python, self

```
class learn:

    def __init__(self,radius=1):
        self.radius = radius
     
    def reset_area(self,new_radius):
        self.radius= new_radius
        self.area = new_radius*new_radius*3.14
        self.circum = 2*3.14*radius
        return area + circum
```

ERROR - `"circum" is not defined.`
- `"area" is not defined.`

Comment: When referencing class members inside a class method, yes - you always need to specify them as `self.something`

Comment: Yes. You need to put `self` as a prefix.

Comment: This is why you need to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

When you set a variable with `self.variable = 'sth'`, that variable sets as class property and is accessible in entire class

But when you use `variable = 'sth'`, it's not class property anymore and is accessible in just that function

If you don't want to have `area` and `circum` as class property, don't use `self`:

```py
...
area = new_radius*new_radius*3.14
circum = 2*3.14*new_radius
return area + circum
```

But if you want to have them outside this method, yes you should use `self`

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared a variable whose name is `circum`, so yes, in this context, you have to refer to the variable you did create, and whose name here is `self.circum`.

Your code creates two new attributes in the object instance, which is probably not what you want; so in this case, removing the `self.` prefix from `area` and `circum` both would probably be closer to what you actually want (assuming you don't have other methods which assume that these attributes exist; but then your `__init__` method should probably create them with some default value, such as perhaps `None`).